# How to spawn a shell using netcat on the client side?

Tags: shell, netcat

I know I can spawn the shell on server side using:

```
nc -l 1111 -e /bin/bash
```

But I want to spawn the shell on the client side.

I tried doing: `nc 127.0.0.1 1111 | /bin/bash`

It works but I can't see the output of the executed commands.

So the question is, is there any way to spawn the shell on the client side using netcat?

Comment: I found a solution : (nc 127.0.0.1 1111 | /bin/bash) | nc 127.0.0.1 2222
But in this, I had to open two ports (one for sending commands and one for receiving output commands). 
I'm still looking for a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work for me, though depends on the version of netcat. Debian has packaged two: "[netcat-traditional](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/netcat-traditional)" and "[netcat-openbsd](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/netcat-openbsd)". The former supports `-e` in both client and server mode, the latter doesn't support it at all.

```
$ nc.traditional localhost 1234 -e /bin/bash

$ nc.openbsd localhost 1234 -e /bin/bash
nc.openbsd: invalid option -- 'e'
```

The one on my OSX doesn't support it either.

If you need to do this with a netcat that doesn't support `-e`, you may need something like this: [How to make bidirectional pipe between two programs?](/questions/53641/how-to-make-bidirectional-pipe-between-two-programs)

Comment: `Rakeshs-MacBook-Air:~ rakesh$ nc -e /bin/bash 127.0.0.1 1111

nc: invalid option -- e`

Not working for me.
I'm on OSX.

Comment: Not working for me in Linux as well.
Which version of netcat are you using?

Comment: @RakeshMane, ah right, there are different versions of netcat, even two packaged in Debian.

Comment: There is also `socat`, very powerful `netcat` replacement. http://blog.stalkr.net/2015/12/from-remote-shell-to-remote-terminal.html